# How does std::greater<> wоrk in a set?

Tags: c++, c++14

I know how std::greater works. But when I read the API of std::greater since C++14 it has a default type of void. So, if we don't pass any template argument to greater it defaults to void as below. But the result is as expected in descending order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template< class T = void >
struct greater;

int main()
{
    std::set<int, std::greater<>> s {4, 5, 6, 7}; // This transforms to std::set<int, std::greater<void>>
}
```

Can someone explain how this specialization works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works by having the call operator be a function template instead of a function. Compare the old version to the new specialisation:

```
// greater<T>
bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;

// greater<void> i.e. greater<>
template< class T, class U>
auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const;
```

---

What makes this *great* is the ability to compare objects of differing types.

This is crucial for example in case where given a string view, you need to look up whether an equivalent `std::string` is stored in a set. Being able to compare string view to a `std::string` allows us to not create a string from that string view. Which is good because `std::string` can potentially be expensive to create.

With the old comparator, it could only compare `std::string` to another `std::string` in which case we would have to create a `std::string` in order to look it up from a set of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to defer instantiation for a particular type to the call of a templated `operator()` instead of instantiationg `greater` for a particular type.

Consider you want to pass an overload set to a function so you can do something like this:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F f){
    f(std::string{});  
    f(42);             
}
```

You cannot pass an overload set to `foo`. You also cannot pass a class template to `foo` (without instantiating it). But you can write a class with an templated `operator()`:

```
struct bar {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T t) {}
};


int main() {
  foo(bar{});  
}
```

In your case passing `greater<>` instead of `greater<int>` is mainly a matter of convenience, but the idea is the same. `greater<>` has a templated `operator()`.

PS: ...and I missed one crucial advantage of `greater<>::operator()` (explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708161/4117728)). `greater<>` allows you to compare elements of different type even when there is no implicit conversion between them or you don't want to trigger the conversion (of course you still need a viable `>`).

Comment: It's also faster to instantiate a templated function than a new type, AFAICR.

Comment: @einpoklum well in case of `greater`its still `greater<void>` that needs to be instantiated plus its `operator()` that needs to be instantiated. Nevertheless interesting point, if you know some reference I'd be glad to read it.

Comment: Odin Holmes' talk in Code::Dive 2017, [The fastest meta-programming in the west](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpVPexZHYrQ).

Comment: @einpoklum nice talk. Terrible color scheme, but otherwise excellent wrap up. Though, I think you misremembered, according to "Bob" instantiating a function ist more expensive (~43:20).